# Stacking div one below another horizontally

Tags: html, css

Stacking div one below another horizontally in fixed width parent div, all the child div's should be placed in fluidic manner.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I need this to be fixed only with CSS but not using JS, here is what I need:

[image: I am expecting this to happen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using flex and absolute position:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  padding: 0 25px;
  justify-content:space-around;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  max-width:0px;
  margin:auto;
}
.child:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.child:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
.child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50px;
  left:-25px;
  bottom:0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, you are almost there but as more children added it's exceeding parent width :(

Comment: @Syed yes this is the non-perfect part :) .. am trying to figure out a trick but at least you have something to work with ;) maybe you will the fix before me :)

Comment: @Syed updated :) it's better now ;) used some padding/margin tricks

Comment: @Syed now it's perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following example uses jQuery. Uses `absolute` positioning and calculation of `left` offset.

```js
const parentNode = $('.parent');
const childNodes = parentNode.find('.child');
const childNodeWidth = childNodes.outerWidth();
const childOffset = (parentNode.width() - childNodeWidth) / (childNodes.length - 1) / parentNode.width() * 100;
let zIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
  childNodes.eq(i).css({
    left: i * childOffset + '%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, ' + parseInt(i * 255 / childNodes.length) + ', 255)',
    zIndex: zIndex++
  });
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rq2ve5sx/)

Comment: add `parseInt` to the color part when you do the division and it will work. Rgb allow only interger values

Comment: also i don't agree there is no CSS solution :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see... I keep forgetting about flex. Nice solution!